# How to drill/mount items on terracotta brick walls?

Tags: basement, mounting

My basement walls are plaster over terracotta block. I understand this is a fragile material, so I was wondering how to go about drilling into it to mount horizontal wood beams for wall paneling? I've recently had the basement waterproofed and floor epoxied, so I'd like to have something besides the bare white walls.

[image: Basement walls]

Answer (score 1):

I am very familiar with that stuff. Contrary is a good description for it. It will not take any kind of concrete screw or masonry nails. It has many large voids and thin walls.

[image]

My suggestion will not be easy but with patience, doable.

You will need to use toggle bolts to hold any framing in place. Since you will be using long pieces floor to ceiling, placing the toggles about 4 to 8" from the ends and approx. 16" apart will hold the furring and any wallboard/drywall you choose to install. You could add construction adhesive to help hold a little, but since the walls are painted, the adhesive will only hold as good as the paint does. Scratching the paint off may help, then again, the adhesive will only hold as good as the surface it is bonding to.

In the picture I supplied you can see there are 3 voids per block face. With the exposed block you have, you can determine where the voids are and drill a series of holes to slip the ends of the toggle bolts into. I suggest using 3/8" toggles. This will require a 3/8" hole drilled in the lumber, and a 5/8" or larger hole(s) in the terracotta. I would also suggest drilling a counterbore in the lumber to get the screw head of the toggle bolt to go below the surface, so it will not interfere with any of the wall finishes.

[image]

Comment: Is a hammer drill or rotohammer a bad idea? My instinct is to use a tile bit to avoid vibration.

Comment: @popham a tile bit or glass bit would be the best, it would have less of a chang to blow out the back side from the vibration. The tile bit with a regular drill would at least get a real hole started before breaking the rest the way through, where a rotary hammer or the like would pop a hole in the terracotta in no time. It may still work, but the toggle bolts are the strongest when the clips that fold up are supported best closest to the bolt itself. The larger the hole, less support is given to the wings, and more prone to breaking the pivot point, which is the weakest place on the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the terracotta on the joist bearing walls, you might anchor a 2x2 to the ceiling and a pressure treated 2x2 to the floor. Then you can install your studs vertically between them without drilling the terracotta.

Comment: That would work well too, using 2X4s on the flat, with a toggle in the center to stabilize it, IMO. It would save a lot of time with the toggles. I'm surprised I didn't think of that myself.. :)

Comment: @Jack, the IRC has that bit allowing flat oriented studs for non-bearing walls. I think technically this could be by the book even without an anchor at the mid-point. There it is: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.5. It's by the book if they're on 16" centers. Meh. Almost certainly for your exact stability reason.